# 'Ambiguous field reference date' error when trying to build cohort analysis

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to build a query to get the user retention from day one to day two. So my idea is to count the `fullVisitorId` on day one then joining a second table (day2) and count the `fullVisitorId` from day one on day two. 
Correct me is my logic is wrong or unclear. I'm tried to translate this with the following query however I have the following error :

`Ambiguous field reference date.`

here is my query :

```
SELECT
      count(Table1.fullVisitorId),
      date
    FROM
      [storied-toolbox-121439:103262044.ga_sessions_20161108] as dayone
    JOIN 
      [storied-toolbox-121439:103262044.ga_sessions_20161109] as daytwo
    on
    dayone.fullVisitorId = daytwo.fullVisitorId
    group by
    date
```

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below addresses error you are getting about Ambiguous field, but does not address the goal you describe you need to achieve about users' retention.
My understanding that question is more about fixing error and then you will try to go further in your task

```
SELECT
   COUNT(dayone.fullVisitorId) as cnt,
   dayone.date as date
FROM [storied-toolbox-121439:103262044.ga_sessions_20161108] as dayone
JOIN [storied-toolbox-121439:103262044.ga_sessions_20161109] as daytwo
ON dayone.fullVisitorId = daytwo.fullVisitorId
GROUP BY 2
```

Comment: Why do you use `group by 2` what does it mean ?

Comment: `group by 2` is equivalent to `group by date' in above query. you can use position of field instead of field name in GROUP BY and ORDER BY

Comment: hum ok thanks. I you said, it's working but the result isn't what I'm expecting. I'll keep digging on that. by the way just download your chrome extension. guess It's a bit over the top for my use but looks interesting :)

Comment: yes, i mentioned that you still need to work on your task - if you will get stuck with this  - i recommend you to post new question with details about your task and good example of  input and desired output - this is important on SO - otherwise it is hard to help. at least for me  - it is easy to code  - but it is hard to read someoneelse's mind and derive details from just simplified mission statements :o)  - check [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) requirements for asked questions